# module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'median_grouped'

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Dispongo del **dataframe** denominado "**tabla**" en la que los datos están agrupados en intrevalos de clase. En la columna "**fi**" se encuentran las frecuencias absolutas de las observaciones. En la columna "**Fi**" disponemos de las frecuencias acumuladas.
Aplicando `scipy.stats`, intento conseguir la mediana agrupada

```
from scipy import stats
#Mediana de una muestra de observaciones 
tabla = {'Rango' : ["0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", "25-30"],
         "LimExaInf" : [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
         "LimExaSup" : [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
         "fi": [6, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4],
         "Fi": [6, 16, 19, 24, 33, 37]}
tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla, dtype = np.float64)
print("\nMediana :", stats.median_grouped(tabla["fi"]))
```

El script me devuelve el error mencionado en el título.

> **AttributeError**: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'median_grouped'
>   Realizando el cálculo aplicando la fórmula

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Intervalo modal** es el intervalo que tiene mayor fecuencia absoluta.

**Li** es el límite inferior del intervalo modal.

Si aplicamos la fórmula, para lo cual he desarrollado el siguiente script

```
N = tabla["fi"].sum()
for i in range (0, tabla.shape[0]):
    if tabla["Fi"][i] > N/2:
        Li = tabla ["LimExaInf"][i]
        Ls = tabla ["LimExaSup"][i]
        ci = Ls - Li
        M = Li + (  ((N/2) - tabla["Fi"][i-1])/ tabla["fi"][i])*ci        
        break
print ("\nMediana :", M)
```

el resultado es 14,17.

Agradeceré ayuda para aplicar correctamente la función anteriormente mencionada.

Comment: le he estado dando vueltas y probando cosas y creo que `statistics.median_grouped(data, intervalo)` está pensada para los datos sin contarlos. He creado un par de tablas con valores que se caben dentro de tus intervalos de clase y frecuencia y me da 14 cuando uso un intervalo de 6 y en otra tabla que conozco tambien el resultado me da un valor parecido. Sigo sin saber si existe algun error de redondeo o que me falte algo, pero creo que la intencion de esas funciones son de usarlas directamente con el dato en crudo.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te señala el mensaje de error no existe un atributo llamado `median_grouped`. Existen `median_absolute_deviation()` y `median_test()`

Despues de los comentarios he sacado esta versión del calculo que requieres basandome en su formula y en la tabla adjunta y no en un built-in. Se puede optimizar más a costa de legibilidad per creo que así es más facil de entender. 
Con un poco más de tiempo y ganas se podria hacer una función que acepte argumentos con los valores de una tabla (media_grouped(*tabla) podria ser un buen comienzo), pero lo dejo como ejercicio para el lector

Cualquier duda comenta de nuevo, un saludo

```
tabla = {
    "LimExacInt": ["0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", "25-30"],
    "fi": [6, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4],
    "Fi": [6, 16, 19, 24, 33, 37],
}

intervalo = 5  # Intervalo de clase
n_2 = max(tabla["Fi"]) / 2
for indice, cf in enumerate(tabla["Fi"]):
    if n_2 < cf:
        l_inf = indice * intervalo
        pcf = tabla["Fi"][indice - 1]
        f = tabla["fi"][indice]
        median_grouped = l_inf + ((n_2 - pcf) / f) * intervalo
        print(median_grouped)
        break
```

Comment: Si sustituimos "data1" por "tabla["fi"]", la respuesta no es correcta. He entrado en el módulo statistics para intentar entender qué hace esta función, y ahora estoy aún más confundido. No entiendo la diferencia entre las funciones "statistics.median" y "statistics.median_grouped" de éste módulo. La cuestión básica es encontrar una función que calcule la mediana, partiendo de una lista de frecuencias absolutas. Me serviría cualquier módulo.

Comment: A ver, aquí tu sabrás más que yo de estadistica. Pero echando un vistazo rapido al concepto de mediana entiendo que no es la media de todos los valores sino el valor que está en el medio (o la media de los dos valores centrales si son elementos pares). Y que en el caso de median_grouped lo que te permite es lo mismo pero sacando la mediana total agrupando por intervalos de 2, 3, 4...etc. ¿Es así? Entonces pienso que tu solucion de 14,17 es incorrecta. Corrigeme por favor si me equivoco

Comment: La mediana es el valor de la variable que deja a su izquierda tantas observaciones como a su derecha. La fórmula para su cálculo cuando disponemos de los datos agrupados en intervalos, es la que he insertado en la figura. El resultado aplicando la misma es 14,17.  La función "median_grouped", debería  (si es que es para calcular la media de datos agrupados), utilizando las variables, calcular internamente frecuencias absolutas, frecuencias acumuladas, intervalos, tamaño de los intervalos y auma de fecuencias, para dar el mismo resultado que el retornado aplicando la fórmula.

Comment: Pues...creo que esa funcion no hace lo que esperas sino que te saca la mediana de todos los valores de la lista que le argumentas con opcion de separarlo por intervalos. Estoy estudiando el problema (no se me da bien las matematicas) porque me ha llamado la atencion. Voy a ver si saco algo en claro

Comment: En ese caso,  ¿qué diferencia hay entre las funciones "statistics.median" y "statistics.median_grouped"?.

Comment: Ahora que más o menos entiendo el problema estoy pensando....y si median_grouped no espera ni tu frecuencia ni el acumulado...y solo necesita la tabla bruta de los datos originales y el intervalo de 5? Haz la prueba con statistics.median_grouped(tablacruda, interval=5) a ver si cuela! Mi solución propuesta da el resultado que buscas, pero si la solución es usan los datos en crudo...mil veces mejor

Answer (score 0):

Jose Rodriguez, la contestación es un poco larga, por la que lo hago aquí.

La mediana es el valor de la variable que deja a su izquierda tantas observaciones como a su derecha. La fórmula para su cálculo cuando disponemos de los datos agrupados en intervalos, es la que he insertado en la figura. El resultado aplicando la fórmula es 14,17.

La función "median_grouped", debería  (si es que es para calcular la media de datos agrupados), utilizando las variables, calcular internamente frecuencias absolutas, frecuencias acumuladas, intervalos, tamaño de los intervalos y la suma de fecuencias, para dar el mismo resultado que el retornado aplicando la fórmula. He hecho la prueba creando el array

```
array([65, 36, 49, 84, 79, 56, 28, 43, 67, 36, 43, 78, 37, 40, 68, 72, 55,
       62, 22, 82, 88, 50, 60, 56, 57, 46, 39, 57, 73, 65, 59, 48, 76, 74,
       70, 51, 40,  7, 56, 45, 35, 62, 52, 63, 32, 80, 64, 53, 74, 34, 76,
       60, 48, 55, 51, 54, 45, 44, 35, 51, 21, 35, 61, 45, 33, 61, 77, 60,
       85, 68, 45, 53, 34, 67, 42, 69, 52, 68, 52, 47, 62, 65, 55, 71, 73,
       50, 53, 59, 41, 54, 41, 74, 82, 58, 26, 35, 47, 50, 38, 70])
```

Si aplicas a este array las funciones **statistics.median** y **statistics.median_grouped** veras que el resultado es el mismo, 14,5, con las dos funciones.

Así que entiendo que "median_grouped" no es la función que busco y no sé para que sirve.

Comment: Pues ni idea, haciendo los pasos de una pakistaní en youtube traducido a python me salen 14,16^ asi que tampoco sé para que sirve median_grouped(). Voy a ver si adorno un poco el codigo y lo pongo de vuelta